# Merging [eu] and [european-union]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Tags [eu](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) and [european-union](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) have identical descriptions:

> For questions specifically related to the EU, but not specifically to a member nation

Although the latter category has more questions tagged, I propose merging both into the [eu](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) tag, using the precedent of existing tag synonyms for [united-states](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) to [usa](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [united-kingdom](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) to [uk](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).

Comment: The real issue here is that the majority of the [tag:eu]-tagged questions do not concern the EU, but [EASA](http://easa.europa.eu). EASA has member states that are not EU members (the usual ones, but still: Switzerland (+Liechtenstein), Norway and Iceland).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merged 'em. Thanks for catching it! [european-union](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) → [eu](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu).